# When LRU is NOT the optimal replacement policy

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I've been googling this topic but still couldnt get a legit answer. So can someone explain with some examples that if we were to use cache memory instead of LRU we would have lower miss rate (better peformance). Or simply when LRU is not an optimal choise.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "use cache memory instead of LRU"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a program that plays a video in an endless loop (e.g. an electronic advertising billboard), assuming the RAM is constrained enough that the whole video can't fit at once.

The most recently used page of memory will contain the most recent section of the video, that *just* played. LRU would be the worst choice, because you're holding onto the parts that have already played, which are the parts that won't be needed for the longest time. They won't be needed again until all other pages are played first, and the video repeats. By definition, such a use case is hitting the *least* recently used pages, over and over.

The optimal page replacement policy in such a situation is one that either preempts the future pages (which is possible in this case because of the periodicity and simplicity of this usage profile) or one which permanently  holds onto some parts of the video (doesn't matter which parts, as they're all played equally) and uses the rest of the space to cycle through the rest of the pages.

Comment: But one of the principles of video compression is by encoding differences between frames. The frame that was just rendered to the display is still immediately useful when rendering the next frame.

Comment: @200_success Fair point!